# Get the key value pair from the table for the subsequence occurence of value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have a Name and Int stored in table, where in Int column has 0 or 1 as its value.

```
N1, 0
N2, 0,
N3, 1
N4, 0,
N5, 1
N6, 0,
N7, 0,
N8, 1.
```

I need the key value pair output as (N1, N3) WHERE in N1 it had 0, then 1 was at N3. Same way (N1, N3), (N4, N5) and (N6, N8)

How can i write the query using SQL efficiently for more than 100k records?

Comment: Which rdbms?  What have you tried?

Comment: MS SQL Server. i have written a stored procedure to join the tables,Above mentioned logic i need to incorporate with this efficiently. Not sure how can loop and get the next occurance of 1 and  Name1, Name2 as pairs as output.

Comment: Assuming your rows are logically ordered by the integer in the name, it's possible to get a `dense_rank()` to work. Or use `lead()`. That is, if your sql server version supports those.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: With Dense_rank() and Lead(), will i be able to get the 3 rows as output (N1, N3) (N4.N5) (N6, N8) out of 8 rows i mentioned? Can u please give me a sample query for the above as i am not much into SQL?

Comment: What's the logic of pairing (N1, N3)?  Why not (N1, N2), (N3, N4)?

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your question, not messages. Read & act on [mcve]. Show code you have tried for this. How far did you get with dnese_rank/lead?

Comment: @Eric : It is to look for next value changes from 0 to 1.